# MySQL Query with select and grouping

Tags: mysql

I would like to select all of the client records that were submitted by 10 but not the client records where 20 was assigned as a representative.  So my desire result would be 2 total records selected for client 2 and 3. 4 is excluded because 20 is part of that set.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
+--------------+--------+----------------+
| Submitted_By | Client | Representative |
+--------------+--------+----------------+
|           10 |      2 |             15 |
|           10 |      2 |             16 |
|           10 |      2 |             17 |
|           10 |      3 |             15 |
|           10 |      3 |             16 |
|           10 |      3 |             19 |
|           10 |      4 |             15 |
|           10 |      4 |             16 |
|           10 |      4 |             17 |
|           10 |      4 |             20 |
+--------------+--------+----------------+
```

Tried

```
SELECT
    Client,
    Submitted_By,
    Representative,
FROM
    client
WHERE
Client = 10 AND Representative != 20
```

Comment: Please format properly your data example. What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes. This seems very easy, so show us what you tried. And include a properly formatted desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a subquery like:

```
SELECT Client, Submitted_By, Representative 
   FROM client 
   WHERE Submitted_By = 10 
   AND Client NOT IN (SELECT Client FROM client WHERE Representative = 20)
```

You wrote you only want "2 total records" returned. Then a `GROUP BY Client`
statement can be used to return two rows, one for each client, from your provided example table.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Done.  Thanks again.